# Check multiple facts in CLIPS

Tags: clips

Let's say I have some facts (I do not know how many there are) like this: lamp x is off. With a defrule I proggressively turn all lamps on so every fact will be: lamp x is on. How do I check every lamp that is on. I know that if there were three lamps I could write:

```
(defrule checkAllLamps
    (lamp 1 is on)
    (lamp 2 is on)
    (lamp 3 is on)
    =>
    (printout t "All lamps are on now")
)
```

But for x lamps?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fact-set query functions for that (chapter `12.9.12` of the [Basic Programming Guide](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/documentation/v630/bpg.pdf)).

```
(deftemplate lamp 
  (slot id (type INTEGER)) 
  (slot state (type SYMBOL)))

(defrule all-lamps-are-on 
  (lamp (state on)) 
  (test (>= (length$ (find-all-facts ((?l lamp)) (eq ?l:state on))) 3)) 
  => 
  (printout t "All lamps are on" crlf))
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to do it without deftemplate though? Using deffacts

Comment: AFAIK fact-set query functions work only with `deftemplates`. You can still use the `deffacts` construct with `deftemplate` facts, you just need to make sure the `deftemplates` are constructed before calling the `deffacts` function. Implied/ordered facts are quite limited in term of features. I'd recommend you to use `deftemplate` facts as much as you can.

Comment: Actually what this rule is checking is whether there are at least three lamps that are on. As long as there are at least three lamps that are on, there can be any number of lamps that are off. It will also execute once for each lamp that is on in excess of two, so if five lamps are on you'll see the "All lamps are on" message three times.

Comment: This is indeed true. I focused in answering the question in the title rather than validating what the OP was really after. Assumption was the OP was providing an example to better clarifying what he was after.

Comment: In general it's a bad idea to use the query functions in the conditions of a rule because when the rule fires the current state of the system may be different than the state of the system when the query function was evaluated. For example, if you assert three lamp facts that are on and then retract the first two that were asserted, the all-lamps-are-on rule will still be activated even though there is only one lamp that is on.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can check whether all of the lamps are on. The checkAllLamps rule treats the case where there are no lamps at all as all lamps being on, whereas the checkAllLampsAtLeastOne rule requires that there is at least one lamp that is on.

```
         CLIPS (6.31 2/3/18)
CLIPS> 
(defrule checkAllLamps
   (not (lamp ? is off))
   =>
   (printout t "All lamps are on now" crlf))
CLIPS> 
(defrule checkAllLampsAtLeastOne
   (exists (lamp ? is on))
   (not (lamp ? is off))
   =>
   (printout t "All lamps are on now" crlf))
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      checkAllLamps: *
For a total of 1 activation.
CLIPS> (assert (lamp 1 is on))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      checkAllLampsAtLeastOne: *,*
0      checkAllLamps: *
For a total of 2 activations.
CLIPS> (assert (lamp 2 is off))
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> (agenda)
CLIPS> (retract 2)
CLIPS> (assert (lamp 2 is on))
<Fact-3>
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      checkAllLampsAtLeastOne: *,*
0      checkAllLamps: *
For a total of 2 activations.
CLIPS>
```